# what to do with ms sql error 40 ""

Tags: sql-server, windows-authentication

I had no problem with my sql server and management studio yesterday, but today it does not connect and show me this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

The only change I had made is changing windows user password, and I connect to sql using windows authentication
what shoul i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

First Check if your sql server agent is running.
Then go to SQL Server configuraion manager->sql Network Configuration->protocols for [server name]
then enable the Named Pipe if it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Error 40 **“provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 – Could not open a connection to SQL Server”on server”** can be occur due to several reasons. Take a look on this KB article and follow the steps discussed in it http://www.sqlserverlogexplorer.com/fix-error-message-40/